# SQL dynamic weekend/3 day date

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I am stuck in getting the right query for my request.

Here is my request- I need to get a dynamic date that goes back to just the 3rd day prior to today (past) and on Thursday of every week- I want Saturday, Sunday, and Monday to be part of my query so that I can include the weekends data in my data extraction as part of Monday's as well. Please let me know if you need more info. Any insight provides is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Darshan- as soon as I get to my computer il provide that info to you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`declare @start_date as date
declare @end_date as date
set @end_date = dateadd(day,-3,getdate())
set @start_date = dateadd(day,-6,getdate())`

Then you can use the right combination of `>`, `<`, and `=` operators with the aforementioned variables in your `where` clause to pull your date range as necessary. I think that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Alexus! This should give me three days prior- that's perfect. Will this also include the weekend's data as part of Monday's data?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "the weekend's data as a part of Monday's data". Essentially, this would give you date parameters that start six days ago, and end three days ago, regardless of it being a weekend or not.

Comment: Correct that's my understanding as well! What I am specifically looking at is that- I don't want to include the weekends as let of the feed! On Thursday you would get Monday's data- but that Monday's data should include Saturday and Sunday! Does that make sense? Hope it does

Comment: You'll need to be more specific, because you said above that you "want Saturday, Sunday, and Monday to be part of my query so that I can include the weekends data in my data extraction as part of Monday's as well". However, in the comment above you said that "I don't want to include the weekends". Please specify which.